# Kotlin DSL automatically add/generate to MutableList

Tags: kotlin, dsl, kotlin-dsl

I've been struggling making DSL to work like this. I'd like to add items inside the lambda to the mutableList inside the persons. Can anybody help with this?

```
persons {
    Person("name")
    Person("name second")
}
```

the expected result after the lambda executed, all those item will be put inside the mutableList like this:

```
mutableListOf(Person("name"), Person("name second"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `Person` is a:

```kotlin
data class Person(val name: String)
```

Then the line `Person("name")` does nothing - it just desclares an unused instance. `Person("name second")` does the same (generally speaking, as it is the last line in lambda, it implicitly returned as the result of lambda expsession and theoretically, it could be handled later; anyway, that DSL syntax won't be working in general case).

You need not just declare instances, but also add them to list. So you need to declare some auxilary function (`person` for instance, to be close to desired syntax) which will do this under the hood:

```kotlin
class Persons {
    val delegate: MutableList<Person> = mutableListOf()

    fun person(name: String, block: Person.() -> Unit = {}) {
        delegate.add(Person(name).also(block))
    }
}

fun persons(block: Persons.() -> Unit) = Persons().also(block).delegate.toList() //mutation was needed only during construction, afterwards consider preserving immutability
```

Usage:

```kotlin
val persons: List<Person> = persons {
    person("name")
    person("name second")
}
```

Comment: I didn't think using function to emulate class creation. Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Not quite exactly as you have but should be able to use something like

```
data class Person(var name: String? = null)

class Persons : ArrayList<Person>() {
    fun person(block: Person.() -> Unit) {
        val person = Person().apply(block)
        add(person)
    }
}

fun persons(block : Persons.() -> Unit): Persons = Persons().apply(block)

fun main() {
    val personList = persons {
        person {
            name = "John"
        }
        person {
            name = "Jane"
        }
    }

    println(personList)
}
```

(This could be expanded then to use some kind of builder pattern to allow use of immutable vals in the data class)

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation, its really helpful